# R generate an simple integer matrix with defined number of row and column

Tags: r, random, matrix, integer

How to generate an integer random matrix with value from {1 ... 15} in r with 9 row and 100 column for instance ?

(My question may be basic but for unknown reasons I can't find a solution)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
matrix(sample.int(15, size = 9*100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 9, ncol = 100)
```

or the more concise version

```
matrix(sample.int(15, 9*100, TRUE), 9, 100)
```

but if you are really going for minimum number of characters (I would not recommend):

```
matrix(sample(15,900,T),9)
```